# How to put image tiles properly without colum gap or row gap in between using only CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML and CSS. For one of my projects, I need to put 16 images into a 4x4 grid of tiles on a webpage. These tiles cannot have gaps between them, and they need to stretch to fill the browser from side to side. They also should only scroll vertically. We are only allowed to use JavaScript or JQuery so I can only use HTML and CSS.

I wrote 4 div elements, each represents a row; inside each div, a span element holds 4 images - that's how I made the 4x4 grid. A code snippet looks like this:

```
/* One row in a div*/
<div class="map">
    <span>
        <img src="map_images/1.png">
        <img src="map_images/2.png">
        <img src="map_images/3.png">
        <img src="map_images/4.png">
    </span>
</div>
```

I also wrote a navigation bar that should float above the background images in the upper right corner:

```
/* 4 div elements of 4 rows before this code*/
<div id="nav">
    <div><a href="foo.html">Foo</a></div>
    <div><a href="boo.html">Boo</a></div>
</div>
```

For the above code, my stylesheet looks like this:

```
.map{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

However, I've encountered several problems at this point.

First, I still have column gaps and row gaps between all 16 images. No matter what values I set map margin and padding to, nothing changes. I even tried negative values, still nothing changed. Can someone tell me how to go about this problem, eliminating all gaps?

Secondly, I googled and learned that z-index can be used to make div float above background; however, this is no working here and it seems that div #nav stays in the upper right corner as a separate div that does take up space, instead of floating above. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: You can't put `img` tags inside a `span`

Comment: `img {display:block;}` will remove the margin beneath each image. Images are inline-block by default. Then, you can add `float:left;` to make them appear next to each other. Don't forget to use a clearfix though, or the height of your divs will collapse.

Comment: @StephenWidom Thank you! That fixed the problem in no time; I also did body {margin:0;} so the background is from side to side. Fixed the second problem according to the first answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I had to do was set `float: left` and `width: 25%` on the images in CSS

```
.map img{
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y8eq47ke/3/)**

Comment: Thank you! That's really a simple fix! I still have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like this? See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/q12bh4se/4/

Snippet :

```css
    body {

      margin: 0px;

    }

    div {

      width: 50%;

      float: left;

    }

    img {

      width: 50%;

      float: left;

    }

    .top-left {

      z-index: 9999;

      position: absolute;

      top: 0;

      left: 0;

      color: white;

    }

    .top-right {

      z-index: 9999;

      position: absolute;

      top: 0;

      right: 0;

      color: white;

    }
```

```html
 <h1 class="top-left">Top Left</h1>
<h1 class="top-right">Top Right</h1>
<div class="row-1-col-1">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/200/200/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/1/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/Dummy-Text/">
</div>
<div class="row-1-col-2">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/200/200/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/1/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/Dummy-Text/">
</div>
<div class="row-2-col-3">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/200/200/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/1/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/Dummy-Text/">
</div>
<div class="row-3-col-3">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/200/200/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/1/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/Dummy-Text/">
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's also what I'm looking for; sorry that I can only choose one answer. But it's great to learn different ways to solve this problem. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

Float left and set the width to 25%. Also I show below how to create a floating menu using the [`:hover` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Ahover).

```css
.map div img {
  width: 25%;
  float:left;
  display: inline-block;
}

#nav {
  width: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
}

#nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  display:none;
}

#nav:hover ul, #nav ul:hover {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  Menu
  <ul>
    <li><a href="foo.html">Foo</a></li>
    <li><a href="boo.html">Boo</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="map">
  <div class="row">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Great way to fix the problem. Sorry I can only choose one answer. But thank you guys really. Learned a lot today.